# Insert EasyUi linkbutton in Datatables

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, jquery-easyui

I use Jquery Datatables (https://www.datatables.net) in my site and I whant insert in a cell a Linkbutton from ui "EasyUi" (http://www.jeasyui.com) loaded via Ajax, but browser show it like plain link and not with a Button link.

This is code that php with Ajax insert in the cell

```
<a href='#' class='easyui-linkbutton'>Test</a>
```

If I use some code out the table it's work fine

Comment: I'm guessing you initialise the button outside the table like this: `$('.easyui-linkbutton').linkbutton({...});`? You'll need to call that again in the drawCallback or add the `data-options` like this: http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/linkbutton.php It might perhaps be worth working up a JSFiddle in order to help us test though.

Comment: Hi, I used linkbutton from markup, not programmatically. I can't initialise outside because I have a button for every line of table.
I use this botton for open an editor for every row.
I can't post it on JSFiddle because code is incapsulated in other element of UI and it's not work separatly. I can't show you because it is in a webserver in a local lan not visible in internet.

Comment: If I don't use Ajax call for load data it's work.
It's an example what I need:
https://jsfiddle.net/skyfox/6ak4wtf9/17/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to set up your buttons in the drawCallback like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#example').DataTable({
        "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
            $(".easyui-linkbutton").linkbutton();
        }
    });
});
```

Working JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/6ak4wtf9/20/). Your JSFiddle didn't work because you were mixing `http` with `https` and so some of your external resources weren't being loaded. Hope that helps.